# Scrape 4chan for alive images

Tags: clojure, web-scraping

I'm trying to learn Clojure recently and I thought writing a simple web app would be a good way to dive in.

This function gets the list of alive threads from the API and reduces, filters and maps until I'm left with a list of image names (which I can append to `"http://i.4cdn.org/wg/"` to get the URL's.).

This is the first time I'm using `defer`/`@` so I'm not that sure if I used them correctly.

Here is the code:

```
(defn scrape []
  (let
    [{:keys [status hey body error] :as resp}
      @(http/get "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/threads.json")]
    (->>
      (json/read-str (resp :body))
      (map #(%1 "threads"))
      (reduce concat [])
      (map #(%1 "no"))
      (map #(str "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/thread/" %1 ".json"))
      (map http/get)
      (map deref)
      (map #(%1 :body))
      (map json/read-str)
      (map #(%1 "posts"))
      (reduce concat [])
      (filter #(not (nil? (%1 "tim"))))
      (map #(str (%1 "tim") (%1 "ext")))
      (print))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't need `:as resp` if only `body` is ever used.
- I'd also drop the `:keys` destructuring if it's not reused.
- While couple of those `map`s make sense, this sequence is also pretty
  repetitive, I'd suggest condensing repeated invocations into a single
  call at least.
- The `(not (nil? ...))` is probably the same as the value itself, so
  just `(filter #(%1 "tim"))` should suffice.
- The function should most likely return the list instead of `print`ing
  it so the files can be examine further in another part of the code.
- Maybe use `mapcat` instead of the `map`/`reduce`/`concat` combination?

The `deref` is fine I think, it also depends on how the calls should be
batched together (or not).

All in all:

```
(ns fourchan.core
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json])
  (:require [org.httpkit.client :as http]))

(defn scrape []
  (->>
   (json/read-str (@(http/get "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/threads.json") :body))
   (mapcat #(%1 "threads"))
   (map #(http/get (str "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/thread/" (%1 "no") ".json")))
   (mapcat #((json/read-str ((deref %1) :body)) "posts"))
   (filter #(%1 "tim"))
   (map #(str (%1 "tim") (%1 "ext")))))
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way to make this code non-blocking without modifying the ->> sturcture?

Comment: What exactly do you want to not block? As the simplest case just wrap the whole block in `future` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestion:

1. Use :key-fn in json/parse to simplify some of the mappings
2. For single argument anonymous function, use % instead of %1
3. Ideally, you should use transducer to compose your mapping functions.  But in this case, you are actually taking advantage of the implementation detail of lazy sequence to parallelize your async http requests. Where each realisation of a lazy sequence chunk allows 32 concurrent async requests to be opened (when you pipe the mapping of http/get to deref)

E.g. this takes ~4 seconds in my machine:

```
(defn scrape []
  (let [{:keys [body]} @(http/get "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/threads.json")]
    (->> (json/read-str body :key-fn keyword)
         (mapcat :threads)
         (map :no)
         (map #(str "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/thread/" % ".json"))
         (map http/get)
         (map deref)
         (map :body)
         (map #(json/read-str % :key-fn keyword))
         (mapcat :posts)
         (filter :tim)
         (map #(str (% :tim) (% :ext))))))
```

Turning into transducer (which avoids realisation of intermediary lazy sequences, i.e. no batching) takes ~24 seconds:

```
(defn scrape []
  (let
      [{:keys [body]} @(http/get "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/threads.json")
       xf             (comp
                       (mapcat :threads)
                       (map :no)
                       (map #(str "http://a.4cdn.org/wg/thread/" % ".json"))
                       (map http/get)
                       (map deref)
                       (map :body)
                       (map #(json/read-str % :key-fn keyword))
                       (mapcat :posts)
                       (filter :tim)
                       (map #(str (% :tim) (% :ext))))]
    (sequence xf (json/read-str body :key-fn keyword))))
```

If you really need to remove the blocking of http requests without relying on the implementation details of lazy sequence, you should consider core.async.  A quick implementation using core.async achieves ~1.2 second in my case.